# How to create multiple tables wit different headers using pdfkit and violab?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdfkit

I tried to find any information and got zero results.
I need to create multiple tables wit different headers, but stuck.
When I'm trying to add second table it's broken.

Second issue is: how to add only at last row TOP border? and last question: is there way to make bold text in last cell?

part of my code:

```
  const pdf = new PDFDocument({
      size: "A4",
      margin: 45,
      autoFirstPage: true,
    }),
    table = new PdfTable(pdf, {
      bottomMargin: 30,
    });
table
    .addPlugin(
      new (require("voilab-pdf-table/plugins/fitcolumn"))({
        column: "title",
      })
    )
    .setColumnsDefaults(column_opts);

  add_table_func(pdf, table); //this makes new table for first time 

  pdf.x = left_margin;
  pdf.moveDown(5);

  add_table_func(pdf, table); //this makes broken table for second time
  pdf.end();


function add_table_func(pdf, table) {
  console.log("pdf.page.width", pdf.page.width);
  table
    .addColumns([
      {
        id: "title",
        header: "Herr Peckewitz, Holger",
        align: "left",
        width: pdf.page.width - 330,
      },
      {
        id: "net",
        header: "Netto",
        width: 50,
      },
      {
        id: "tax",
        header: "MwSt. 5%",
        width: 60,
      },
      {
        id: "gross",
        header: "MwSt. 16%",
        width: 60,
        // border: ["L", "B", "T", "R"],
      },
      {
        id: "total",
        header: "Brutto",
        width: 70,
        // border: data.title == undefined ? ["B"] : [],
        renderer: function (tb, data) {
          table.pdf.fontSize(10).font("./IBM_Plex_Sans/IBMPlexSans-Light.ttf");
          return data.total;
        },
      },
    ])
    .onPageAdded(function (tb) {
      tb.addHeader();
    });

  table.addBody([
    {
      title: "ISANA Cremedusche Pearl, 300 ml ",
      net: 0.59,
      tax: "0",
      gross: 0.1,
      total: 0.69,
    },
    {
      title: "Liefergebühr",
      net: 0.73,
      tax: "0",
      gross: 0.12,
      total: 0.85,
    },
    {
      net: 1.32,
      tax: "0",
      gross: 0.22,
      total: 1.54,
      last_field: true,
    },
  ]);
}
```

[how is it now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uo4Sv.jpg) ;

[how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/je3cp.png) ;